# R split string and then sum by character

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

I have a data frame with one column of characters. Some of rows have several characters separated by commas.

For example:
| Category |
| -------- |
| A    |
| A, B   |
|A, B, C |
|B, C|

I want to separate all the categories and sum the frequencies for each:
| Category | Frequency |
| -------- | -------------- |
| A    | 3           |
| B   | 3            |
|C | 2|

How might I do this in R?

Comment: `table(unlist(strsplit(as.character(df$Category), ',')))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% separate_rows(category, sep = ',') %>% count(category, name = 'frequency')
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  category frequency
  <chr>        <int>
1 A                3
2 B                3
3 C                2
```